# How Does AnimationNodes Create This GUI Item?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, animation-nodes

I'm attaching the image of one GUI element which Animation Nodes can produce in the Nodes window. This does not seem to be from "context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog()" (sorry, I'm not very good at Python and Animation Nodes is complicated compared to single file examples I've seen). Is this just a customization of "invoke_props_dialog", or is this something completely custom? Is there any tutorial anyone can suggest which would describe the process of creating something like this for inclusion in the nodes editor?

[image]

Comment: I think invoke_props_dialog is only for operator UIs, not nodes. Did you try right click -> "edit source"? You should also clarify if you mean the two buttons on the top or the sockets below them, or the whole UI.

Comment: I've looked at the source, but it is complicated and I'm new to Python. I wasn't able to decipher what the code does. That's why I'm asking about tutorials...I'm looking for something to explain in more detail how to build nodes (I have no idea how nodes might differ from operator UIs).

Comment: Did you look at the custom nodes example in Blender? You can find it in the text editor, Templates -> Python -> Custom Nodes. About this question: maybe you should rewrite it, it's not clear to me what exactly you are asking. Should we explain all aspects of writing a node UI, or just some specific element in your screenshot? In the title you ask for a "GUI Item", but which of the items in the screenshot do you mean exactly?

Comment: @B.Y.O.B. I was trying to find out if these nodes used something similar to an "invoke_props_dialog" because I like how this works...I was unable to figure out a single function call to look up and read about the API definition (sorry, I don't know what to call that function). Basically, I was hoping there might be a tutorial URL someone could point out which applies to learning this, e.g., something which might annotate the templates (which I didn't know about until yesterday). Your other answer in another thread about invoke_props_dialog was perfect...it told me what topic I needed to read.